# How to get dynamically a size of a drag clone image using jquery

Tags: jquery, size

When I drag a image on droppable area then I want to know the selected image size.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/20/) I did some code.but every time it gives only the first dragged image size.  can anybody help to sole this problem?

In some other discussion there discuss about actual image size not about the clone drag image. 
only get the id of first image. not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on this: http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/21/

I changed

```
var imgWidth = $("#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .draggable").width();
var imgHeight = $("#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .draggable").height();
alert("width: "+ imgWidth +"Height: "+imgHeight);
```

to:

```
alert("Width: "+ui.draggable.width() + " Height: "+ui.draggable.height());
```

EDIT:

Add this to your js code to get the dimension of an image which is clicked in `#working-area`. Take care to add the right class name ;-)

```
$('#working-area .myclass').live('click', function(event) {
        alert("Width: "+$(this).width() + " Height: "+$(this).height());
    });
```

EDIT 2:

To get the position of your dragged element try something like that:

```
$('#working-area .myclass').live('mouseup', function(event) {
         alert(event.pageX);
});
```

Here's http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/22/ an full example.

Comment: @Sarah thanks. I have a one more problem. can you please solve that?  I want the position of drag and drop image. any time when I drag it the position will be change.   how to do it?

Comment: is it possible to get the dimension when the image is select.?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the position of the image when you moving it around in `#working-area´? What do you mean with dimension?

Comment: yes want the position of the image when you moving it around in `#working-area. and also is it possible to get the dimension when the image is select? because for the first time when I drop it on "#working-area" only then I get the dimension.

Comment: I changed my answer and posted also an event to get the dimension of an clicked image in #working-area

Comment: Added another change to get the position of a dragged element

Comment: I want that image only move between this "#working-area" , so alert(event.pageX);--this gives the co-ordinate of whole page. how to solve this? I want the position when the image drag and drop on "#working-area" also

Comment: when I click one image from another first time width and height return 0. you can take look on [mysite](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: Hmm I don't see the problem you mentioned on your site.